# How to list all databases with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I want to be able to list all databases with ActiveRecord.

So I need an ActiveRecord equivalent of the following command in the terminal:

```
psql --host 192.168.0.100 --port 5432  --username postgres --list
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know PostgreSQL, but if there is a SQL query which return this information you can do this:

```
sql = "select * from ... your sql query here"
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Looks like this is the SQL you need:

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database
WHERE datistemplate = false;
```