# How to list postgresql database using ruby pg gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Sorry for the basic question. I'm a newbie with postgresql.
I want to use some gem (the pg gem?) to find out if a certain postgresql databases exists.

Is there something like?

```
PG.does_exist?('my_test_db')
```

Or will it throw an exception if the database doesn't exist when I simply try to connect?

```
begin
  con = PG.connect :dbname => 'my_test_db'
rescue PG::Error => e
  puts e.message
ensure
  con.close if con
end
```

Which still leaves me with the question of how to list the databases that exist.

background:
using the command line I can execute:

```
psql -lt
```

where I can see all my databases. Using really ugly text manipulation you could query if a database exists. But surely there has to be a way to do it using a ruby gem.

Comment: You're using Rails, so use Active Record. Don't use pg, as you're dropping down to a level where you have to use DBM-specific code, tying your code to that database manager, which isn't a good idea. *IF* you have to do so, then isolate that code into as small a section as possible, because that's what you'll be modifying if you convert to a different DBM. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24322440/128421 for more information.

Comment: Tried the sql query at that link and it didn't work. Don't mark this as a duplicate because it isn't. I'm not asking on how to do the equivalent using activerecord: I asked for psql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also connect to the `template1` database and then list all of the databases with

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false;
```

so something like

```
# Output list of all databases
conn = PG.connect( dbname: 'template1' )
conn.exec( "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false;" ) do |result|
  result.each do |row|
    puts row.values_at('datname')
  end
end
```

Comment: wow, it worked. It printed out all the databases i have. total black magic.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer since I figured out mostly on my own how to check if the database existed or not. But this answer I could not have figured out on my own, being a total newbie at this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

It raises a `PG::ConnectionBad` exception.

```
PG.connect dbname: "nonexistent"
# => PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  database "nonexistent" does not exist
```

Rescue that to find out if a db exists.

```
def db_exists?(name)
  PG.connect dbname: "nonexistent"
rescue PG::ConnectionBad => e
  false
end

db_exists?("nonexistent") # => false
db_exists?("exists") # truthy Connection object
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks so much for confirming.